# Prometheus Rules Error

Tags: prometheus

I'm trying to get prometheus alerts up and running, but when defining an alert, it always tells me that the syntax is wrong

Command I'm using to start prometheus

```
./prometheus -config.file=prometheus.yml -alertmanager.url http://localhost:9093
```

Here is the error that I get

```
prometheus, version 0.15.1 (branch: master, revision: 64349aa)
  build user:       julius@julius-thinkpad
  build date:       20150727-17:56:51
  go version:       1.4.2
INFO[0000] Loading configuration file prometheus.yml     file=main.go line=173
ERRO[0000] Error loading rules, previous rule set restored: error parsing /home/ubuntu/alert.rules: Parse error at line 4, char 4: alert summary missing  file=manager.go line=348
```

here is the alert.rule file

```
ALERT node_down
  IF up == 0
  FOR 5m
  LABELS {
    severity="critical"
  }
  ANNOTATIONS {
      summary = "Instance {{$labels.instance}} down",
      description = "{{$labels.instance}} of job {{$labels.job}} has been down for more than 5 minutes."
  }
```

And this is my prometheus.yml file

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s 
  evaluation_interval: 15s 
'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  - "/home/ubuntu/alert.rules"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    target_groups:
    - targets: ['localhost:9100','xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a rather old version of Prometheus which had a slightly different syntax around alerts. Try a more recent version.

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much. I was using version 0.15 (and I don't know why). the one that worked was 1.5

Comment: See What is the correct formatting for alert rules? (https://github.com/prometheus/docs/issues/907 )